# total in repeater footer, itemdatabound in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, itemdatabound

---

I want to sum the total of the gender at the repeater footer using vb.net by using item data bound, the behind code is wrong cause I don't know how to do it...

FRONT CODE

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repGender" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("GENDER")%>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                           <%# Eval("TOTAL")%></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                        <td>Grand Total</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

BEHIND CODE

```
Protected Sub repGender_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repGender.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, ""))
        Else e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer
            


        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we need to define a simple total var at the form's "class" level. it only needs to persist during the data bind operation.

So, given your above markup, then we have this code to load the repeater.

```
Dim MyTotal As Integer

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT Gender, count(*) as TOTAL
        FROM Employee
        GROUP BY Gender"

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, mycon)
            mycon.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    MyTotal = 0
    repGender.DataSource = rstData
    repGender.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And with your markup we see/get this:

[image]

And our data row bind event looks like this:

```
Protected Sub repGender_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repGender.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or
        e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        ' We don't have lable or text box with an "id" in repeat
        ' section, (can't use find control unless you assign "id" to these controls).
        ' so, lets grab the whole data row used for binding

        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem

        MyTotal = MyTotal + gData.Item("TOTAL")

    End If

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer Then

        ' set the total value in footer
        Dim lblTotal As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblTotal")
        lblTotal.Text = MyTotal

    End If

End Sub
```